Why does WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE behave like WDA_MONITOR in this case?
I've written the following code to hide my Tkinter window from being visible in screenshots. I'm trying to make a transparent, click-through overlay that adds an effect to the area behind it, which I capture using mss.
The window that's created goes black instead of transparent, which seems to be the intended effect of using the WDA_MONITOR flag, and not WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE.
The docs state that there's compatibility from Windows 10 Version 2004, and I'm running this on Windows 11.
self.width = 1500
self.height = 750

self.root.title("App")
self.root.geometry('%dx%d' % (self.width, self.height))
self.root.resizable(False, False)

self.bg = Canvas(self.root, width=self.width, height=self.height, bg='white', highlightthickness=0)
self.bg.pack()

hwnd = self.bg.winfo_id()
styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
styles |= WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles)
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 16777215, 255, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA)


user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity.argtypes = wintypes.HWND, wintypes.DWORD
user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity.restype = wintypes.BOOL

WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE = 0x00000011


result = user32.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(self.root.winfo_id(), WDA_EXCLUDEFROMCAPTURE)
if not result:
    raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
else:
    print("SetWindowDisplayAffinity successfully applied!")

Removing the SetLayeredWindowAttributes call results in no content protection at all.

Whether have you tried to use SetWindowDisplayAffinity in normal Win32 applications (like Notepad)?

I used a different app to hide processes from screenshots (uses SetWindowDisplayAffinity internally) and it works well - makes them transparent and not black. It works on notepad and my tkinter window as well.

I set the SetWindowDisplayAffinity code to run a second after root.mainloop() and it seems to work as expected. I guess it didn't before since the window didn't exist at the time of execution? Still curious about why SetLayeredWindowAttributes caused it to behave differently.
